# Vim - how to browse using vim, leave and stay in browsed location

Tags: vim, terminal

I've spent some time of searching internet and vim man with no luck.
After `vim .` I'd like to browse in vim and be able to leave and stay in given location in terminal.
 Is there any possibility to achieve that?

Comment: What does "leave and stay" mean?

Comment: vim .
than browse with arrows and enter
than leave from browse and be in browsed location like
tmp/ -> vim . -> tmp/my/desired/location -> leave -> in terminal I'd like to be in my desired location

Comment: You mean you want to change the working directory of the shell from which you started Vim?

Comment: yes, indeed I want to change working directory in shell

Comment: [Midnight Commander](https://midnight-commander.org/) (a file manager) solves the problem [the following way](https://github.com/MidnightCommander/mc/blob/master/contrib/mc-wrapper.sh.in) — `mc-wrapper` runs `mc -P`, the option makes `mc` to write its last directory before exiting to a known file; then the wrapper does `cd` into that directory. `vim` doesn't have anything like this so you have to implement it yourself: catch `VimLeave` autocommand, save the current directory; `cd` into the directory in a wrapper.

Comment: @phd the use case is that I m on the remote machine with limited options. I wanted to quickli cd through locations with vim. I cannot install additional programmes / commands.

Comment: @PawełWitek Then you're completely out of luck, sorry. On a multiprocessing operating systems every process has its own current directory and none can change the directory for the parent process. Without cooperation from the shell no subprocess (whether it's `mc` or `vim`) could change the current directory of the parent shell on exit.

Answer (score 2):

I think this [link](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/22947/why-does-cd-not-change-the-directory) is your answer If you want to change shell directory from vim.